# How to implement Map with default operation in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

```
class DefaultListMap[A, B <: List[B]] extends HashMap[A, B] {
    override def default(key: A) = List[B]() 
  }
```

I wan't to create map `A -> List[B]`. In my case it is `Long -> List[String]` but when I get key from map that doesn't have value I would like to create empty `List` instead of `Exception` being thrown. I tried different combinations but I don't know how to make code above pass the compiler.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I got around in my case by using
`code

val map = new HashMap[Long, List[String]]() {
    override def default(key: Long) = List[String]()
  }
`

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Why not to use withDefaultValue(value)?

```
scala> val m = Map[Int, List[String]]().withDefaultValue(List())
m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,List[String]] = Map()

scala> m(123)
res1: List[String] = List()
```

Comment: please be aware of [the scala SDK issue with default values with `Map`s](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/8099). `m(123)` will work, but `m.get(123)` will give you `None`.

Answer (score 26):

Rather than using `apply` to access the map, you could always use `get`, which returns `Option[V]` and then `getOrElse`:

```
map.get(k) getOrElse Nil
```

One great feature of the **scalaz** *functional-programming library* is the unary operator `~`, which means "or zero",as long as the value type has a "zero" defined (which `List` does, the zero being `Nil` of course). So the code then becomes:

```
~map.get(k)
```

This is doubly useful because the same syntax works where (for example) your values are `Int`, `Double` etc (anything for which there is a `Zero` typeclass).

---

There has been a great deal of debate on the scala mailing list about using `Map.withDefault` because of how this then behaves as regards the `isDefinedAt` method, among others. I tend to steer clear of it for this reason.

Comment: Interesting answer. However, this move where is done the management of undefined items from the map creation to the map access. In my case, I need to pass a Map to a method which already has its own default behavior, that I want to override (for a test). And I cannot change the code that read the map.

Comment: This is a great answer because it make clear in the calling code where a value is coming from if it's not in the map. Less magic.

Comment: and now can be written as: map.getOrElse(k, Nil)

Answer (score 11):

There's a method `withDefaultValue` on `Map`:

```
scala> val myMap = Map(1 -> List(10), 2 -> List(20, 200)).withDefaultValue(Nil)
myMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,List[Int]] = Map((1,List(10)), (2,List(20, 200)))

scala> myMap(2)
res0: List[Int] = List(20, 200)

scala> myMap(3)
res1: List[Int] = List()
```

Comment: And there's also a `withDefault`, which takes a function.

Comment: please be aware of [the scala SDK issue with default values with `Map`s](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/8099). `myMap(3)` will work, but `myMap.get(3)` will give you `None`.

Answer (score 4):

Why do you want to manipulate a map when it has already a method for this?

```
val m = Map(1L->List("a","b"), 3L->List("x","y","z"))  
println(m.getOrElse(1L, List("c"))) //--> List(a, b)
println(m.getOrElse(2L, List("y"))) //--> List(y)
```

Comment: See my comment to @oxbow_lakes: this is not the same as what is asked by the OP. It manages default at map access, instead of at the map creation.

Answer (score 2):

**withDefault** can also be used.

```
/** The same map with a given default function.
 *  Note: `get`, `contains`, `iterator`, `keys`, etc are not affected
 *  by `withDefault`.
 *
 *  Invoking transformer methods (e.g. `map`) will not preserve the default value.
 *
 *  @param d     the function mapping keys to values, used for non-present keys
 *  @return      a wrapper of the map with a default value
 */
 def withDefault[B1 >: B](d: A => B1): immutable.Map[A, B1]
```

Example:

```
scala> def intToString(i: Int) = s"Integer $i"
intToString: (i: Int)String

scala> val x = Map[Int, String]().withDefault(intToString)
x: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String] = Map()

scala> x(1)
res5: String = Integer 1

scala> x(2)
res6: String = Integer 2
```

Hope this helps.