# Scala HashMap of Lists: simpler default?

Tags: list, scala, hashmap, overriding, default

I need a HashMap of Lists.  Normally I do this:

```
val lists = mutable.HashMap[String,List[Int]]() { 
  override def default(key: String) = {
    val newList = List[Int]()
    this(key) = newList
    newList
  }
}
```

so that I can then simply write things like

```
lists("dog") ::= 14
```

without having to worry about whether the "dog" List has been initialised yet.

Is there a cleaner way to do this?  I find myself typing out those five default override lines again and again.

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What about `withDefaultValue()`?

```
val lists = new mutable.HashMap[String,List[Int]].withDefaultValue(Nil)

lists("dog") ::= 13
lists("cat") ::= 14
lists("dog") ::= 15  //(13, 15)
```

## See also

- [How to implement Map with default operation in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830458)

Comment: Excellent!  Just the ticket.  This is why I love stackoverflow.