# Scala attribution to a default map

Tags: scala, dictionary, default

I'm trying to understand [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14222367/1595865), pertaining to Map with default values:

```
val lists = new mutable.HashMap[String,List[Int]].withDefaultValue(Nil)

lists("dog") ::= 13
lists("cat") ::= 14
lists("dog") ::= 15  //(13, 15)
```

As I understand it, scala uses "nested" functions to represent a immutable list. A unfortunate side effect is that iterating the immutable list returns the elements in *reverse order*.

To avoid the reverse order, I've tried to implement this using a ArrayBuffer:

```
val lists = new mutable.HashMap[String,mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int]].withDefault(_=>ArrayBuffer())

lists("dog").append(1)
println( lists("dog") ) //prints "ArrayBuffer()"
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. It seems scala doesn't actually *put* the default value back on the map, and keeps returning empty ArrayBuffers

In the end, I'm using the following code:

```
val lists1 = new mutable.HashMap[String,mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int]]
val lists= lists1.withDefault( x=>{val n= mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int](); lists1(x)=n; n})
```

This works, but seems unnecessarily complex. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit non-obvious how the `::=` really works. It uses a specified function `::` (prepend) on the list, then assigns the result of the function (`=`) back to the map under a specified key.

If you want to have quick appends, not only prepends, and still have an immutable collection as a value in the map, use a `Vector`:

```
val map = mutable.Map[String, Vector[Int]]().withDefaultValue(Vector())
```

Now, a `Vector` has [`:+` method](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Vector), which returns a copy of the vector with element appended, which is perfect. That means, when you consider the explanation of `::=`, that you can do this:

```
map("dog") :+= 7
map("cat") :+= 3
map("dog") :+= 11
```

And the results:

```
scala> map("cat")
res4: Vector[Int] = Vector(3)

scala> map("dog")
res5: Vector[Int] = Vector(7, 11)
```

Comment: I found `::=` easier to understand when I realized it works just like the `+=` operator. `a::=b` translates to `a=a::b`, just like `a+=b` translates to `a=a+b`. Thanks for the tip on `Vector`, it looks exactly what I was looking for

Comment: What if instead of Vector (immutable), I'd still like to use an ArrayBuffer (mutable)?

Comment: @ostefano Then you have to change some bits and pieces, starting with the map definition: `val map = mutable.Map[String, mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int]]().withDefault(_ => mutable.ArrayBuffer())`, and then the update: `map("dog") +== 7`.