# How to make a Map string as keys and functions as values in scala?

Tags: scala, collections, functional-programming

What I would like to do is something like this :

```
val myMap: Map[String, => String] = Map(
  "name1" -> {//functions that does stuff to generate some string},
  "name2" -> {//functions that does something else to return some other string},
   ...
)
```

Is that even possible? How would I achieve that?
My goal is to have the function evaluate when I get it from the map.

Comment: To clarify: you want it to be impossible to recover the function that creates the string; it will just create the string when you ask for it from the map?  Or it's okay if there's some way to retrieve the function also, so long as it's also easy to get the corresponding string?

Comment: I must say I do not understand you question. Could you give code example for both situations in Scala? (I am still fairly new to this language or to functional programming).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing you'll get is a Map[String, () => String]

```
val myMap = Map(
    "name1" -> { () => generateString() },
    "name2" -> { () => generateString() }
)

val name1 = myMap("name1")()
```

You could also create your own map and override the default function

[How to implement Map with default operation in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830458/how-to-implement-map-with-default-operation-in-scala)